# unable to get json response coming from REST web service in html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf-rest

I have a JSON response coming from REST web service and want to bind that data to html using jQuery. Looks like its not even hitting web service url which I have provided in my jquery.
Url is working fine which gives me JSON data in browser but jQuery I am using unable to get any content from this. I am pasting my code here, plz let me know if some one can help.
While debugging script its directly going on error section in ajax call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
        GetData();

    });

    function GetData() {

        //  alert(textblock.value);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8092/api/Employees",
            data: "{'employeeId'= '" + 1234 + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                var results = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                alert(msg);
                alert(results);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('here');
                var tt = result.text;
                alert(tt);
            }
        });
    }



</script>
```

Comment: Is the page being served from `http://localhost:8092` also?

Comment: may be the data param requires this format: '{"employeeId":"' + 1234 + '"}' ?

Comment: @Pointy - the html page which is calling this is 'http://localhost:39627/test/test5.htm'  Web service url using'http://localhost:8092'

Comment: The ports must match or else the request won't be allowed.

Comment: Thanks Pointy ..let me try doing that.

Comment: I changed a port no. with the same port localhost:8092, now getting Status - 404 and Status text - Not found

Comment: no..its an integer id i am passing as value i/p to call service

Comment: Thanks all for your time and comments..!

Answer (score 0):

finally i am able to get data now.
I added below properties in $.ajax:

processData: false,
async: false,